# Debug 'NaN' errors for fractions in python

Tags: python, function, nan, fractions

Apologies for such a basic question, but I don't understand where does my mistake come from ...

I have the following function:

```
def computeFraction(ratio1, ratio2):
    if ratio1 == 'NaN' or ratio2 == 'NaN':
        fraction = 0.
    if ratio1 == 'NaN' and ratio2 == 'NaN':
        fraction = 0.
    else:
        fraction = float(ratio1) / float(ratio2)
    return fraction
```

and now apply it...

```
for name in my_dataset.iteritems():
    all_messages = float(name[1]['to_messages']) + float(name[1]['from_messages'])
    all_poi_messages = float(name[1]['from_this_person_to_poi']) + float(name[1]['from_poi_to_this_person'])
    name[1]['fraction_total_poi'] = computeFraction(all_poi_messages, all_messages)
```

...and still got NaN values (specifically: it prints 'nan') when calling `my_dataset[person]['fraction_total_poi']`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could it be because `ratio2` is 0 for some persons (that is, devision by zero)?

Comment: hmm in the example I am checking with, ratio2 = nan ...

Comment: Is it 'nan' or 'NaN'? If the input `ratio2` is 'nan' then your check is missing it because of the case. Make your checks case insensitive.